# POST to php via AJAX with json data

Tags: php, jquery, json

Trying to post textbox values to database via json .getJSON - at this point I'm just trying to see if the json post to the page, I have the UPDATE query working fine...

following is not posting as desired:

CODE:

```
$(document).on("click", ".submit", function(event){
    alert($(this).text());

    var form_data = {
        FDID: $('.fdid-1').val(),
        CHOICE1: $('.choice-1').val(),
        CHOICE2: $(".choice-2").val()
        };      

    $.getJSON("modify.php",form_data,function(data){
        switch(data.retval){
            case 0: $("#status").html("Update successful!");
            break;
            case 1: $("#status").html("Unable to update!");
            break;
            default: $("#description").html("Database error, please try again.");
            break;
            }
    });
});
```

modify.php:

```
<?php

header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
header("access-control-allow-origin: *");

$fdid = json_decode($_POST['FDID']);
$choice1 = json_decode($_POST['CHOICE1']);
var_dump($choice1);
// This is in the PHP file and sends a Javascript alert to the client
$message = $fdid;
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
?>
```

MORE of CODE:

```
$.each( data, function ( i, val ) {

            ($('<div>')
            .attr({
                'data-role': 'collapsible',
                'data-content-theme': 'c',
                'data-collapsed': 'true',
                'id': 'cResults'
            })
            .html('<h4>' + this.LastName + ', ' + this.FirstName + '</h4>'
            + '<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search Choices..." data-inset="true" class="makecollapsibleul">'
            + '<li><form id="productForm" action="modify.php" method="post">'
            + '<label for="fdid-1">FDID:</label>'
            + '<input type="text" name="fdid-1" class="fdid-1" value=' + this.FDID + '>'
            + '</li><li>' 
            + '<label for="text-1">Choice 1:</label>'
            + '<input type="text" name="choice-1" class="choice-1" value=' + this.C1 + '>'
            + '</li><li>' 
            + '<label for="text-2">Choice 2:</label>'
            + '<input type="text" name="choice-2" class="choice-2" value=' + this.C2 + '>'
            + '</li><li>' 
            + 'IP: ' + this.IPADDRESS + '</li><input type="submit" class="submit" value="UPDATE" /></form><li>' 
            + 'Pick Date: ' + this.PICKDATE + '</li>'
            + '</ul>'))
            .appendTo('#primary');

                    //$(".title").append('<li>'+orderNum+' -- '+itemNum+'</li>');

            $('#makecollapsible').collapsibleset().trigger('create');
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
```

Comment: SO what is the problem? Errors maybe or what?

Comment: Unless the form fields contain JSON data, you shouldn't be calling `json_decode()`.

Comment: first part I thing submit is not submitting. I'm also not sure in PHP how to get the $_POST if that gets the full json or can be separated by element?

Comment: do I need to json_encode form_data? or just use the string that is sent?

Comment: It looks like you're creating lots of duplicate IDs in your `$.each()` loop. IDs have to be unique. You should use classes instead. And to bind an event handler to dynamically-created elements, you need to use delegation with `.on()`.

Comment: can you give an example? I'm very new to jquery and not real sure of proper format.

Comment: changed id's to class

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: `$("#makecollapsible .makecollapsibleul .productForm").on("click", ".submit", function(event){
    alert($(this).text());
 });`   Don't think I have it in the right elements?

Comment: `$(document).on("click", ".submit", function(event){
    alert($(this).text());
 });` fixed the click event problem, - I'll start a new question because now the FDID that is showing as the parameter is from the first element in the collapsible and not the one clicked...? Could it be because I'm using $(document) and not the lower levels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be calling `json_encode()` to get the parameters. They're sent using `www-form-urlencoded` format, and PHP takes care of decoding them.

You need to call `json_encode` to encode the result you want to send back.

```
<?php

header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
header("access-control-allow-origin: *");

$fdid = $_POST['FDID'];
$choice1 = $_POST['CHOICE1'];
//var_dump($choice1);
// This is in the PHP file and sends a Javascript alert to the client
$message = $fdid;
$result = array('retval' => 0,
                'code' => "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>");
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Comment: ok, can't check this until submit is working... updated code above to show more...

Comment: seems like the issue is the submit button is wrapped in the collapsible element and I think that may have something to do with it? tried the: '$(".save").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // your code
});' by itself and nothing...

Answer (score 0):

You know that `$.getJson()` does, according to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/),

> Load JSON-encoded data from the server using a GET HTTP request.

So you won't find any values in `$_POST`. Use `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST` to get your data.

Just noticed that you don't have an element with `id="save"` but one with `class="save"`. As submit events are only fired by `<form>` elements, try to attach a click callback to your button like this:

```
$(".save").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // your code
});
```